# GODOT - Select an array based on a dynamic variable

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have 5 arrays created in a function. When I call that function I pass in a "type" with the call (it's the only parameter the function accepts). I want to grab one of the arrays based on that type which is passed in.

So, for example, say I call `_get_random_message('closer')` I would want to get the `pool_closer` array from within the function.

I have it working, at present, with a match statement (and it works fine) but it's a lot of extra code I'd rather not have in there if I don't have to!

I would like do something like (and I tried this and it didn't work):

`var pool_to_use = get("pool_" + str(type))`

I have searched and searched to no avail so I was hoping somebody here could help me out with how to get that array based on the passed in variable.

Thanks for any/all help!

Comment: How exactly did `get` not work? And where is the code (an node, resource, something else)? I believe there should be another approach.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a dictionary. You can use the "type" as key for the dictionary, and as value the array. That would make the code shorter, and will make it easier to add more arrays. I believe you are going to need to initialize the dictionary with the arrays you want, which you can do in `_init`:

```
var _arrays:Dictionary

func _init() -> void:
    _arrays = {
        "closer": []
    }

func _get_random_message(type_name:String) -> Array:
    return _arrays.get(type_name)
```

Comment: Ah this is good!  I think I can adapt my code to work with this (what I need to do isn't _exactly_ this but I can alter it to fit my needs)! Thanks so much :D